# Export/Package Vaadin Application

Tags: java, jar, vaadin

I want to be able to share my application with other people, but can't figure out how to package it / export it so that other people can also use it. I know I can use its jar, but that requires some use of Command Prompt. How would I export properly to make it run as a desktop app/web app?

Comment: Make a war file, this includes the whole thing you need to start it in a servlet engine (Like tomcat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Web app framework

Vaadin is a [framework for building web apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_framework). Applications created with the framework are supposed to be distributed via Internet (accessible via a web browser).

In brief details, the process can be described as:

1. Once you have developed an application, you should deploy it to a [Servlet container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container), such as [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat), [Jetty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server)), and so on. Application should be packaged in *production mode*. This ensures minification and bundling of the front-end resources. You end up with an artifact to deploy, either a [WAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)) file or an [EAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAR_(file_format)) file.
2. Obtain a server on the network or internet. Either:

   - Buy space from a hosting provider such as a [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) or [DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean).
   - Provide your own server hardware.
3. Install the Tomcat there if there is not one.

   - For example, look at this article, for a example : [How To Install Apache Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [Configuring WAR Deployment with the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-war-deployment-with-the-heroku-toolbelt))
4. Once your web container is started, you users will be available to use your application via the [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) your server has. In case you want to have a dedicated name, you can buy a [domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name).

### Progressive web application (PWA)

Another aspect, is that you can develop your web application as a [progressive web application (PWA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_application). Still, the application runs in the browser, but an icon prompt for installing software will be added to your main page(in the browser). A user can click it and the application will be installed. But to do that you have to follow the requirements listed here : [Application installation requirement](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/pwa/tutorial-pwa-introduction.html#application-installation-requirements)

But, generally, Vaadin is not the right tool, if you want to create applications that are installed locally. I am also wondering, where you have found information that it can be installed? :)

Comment: Ah, I see. I was under the impression that I could make it a desktop-usable app using its created JAR/WAR file. Would using PWA be the closest to a desktop app without requiring a change in software? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is the case. It would be the closest :)